# How do i make javascript work in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have the code below, its working outside *WordPress*, but when i add to the WordPress site the script fails. I have tried using a plugin and separating the code as shown, then putting the JS code separate
I am not sure where the problems is since am not good with JS.
Any one point me to the right direction and i will appreciate.

```
< script language = "JavaScript" >
  function calculate() {
    // Get the user's input from the form. Assume it is all valid.
    // Convert interest from a percentage to a decimal, and convert from
    // an annual rate to a monthly rate. Convert payment period in years
    // to the number of monthly payments.
    var principal = document.loandata.principal.value;
    var interest = document.loandata.interest.value / 100 / 12;
    var payments = document.loandata.years.value;

    // Now compute the monthly payment figure, using esoteric math.
    var x = Math.pow(1 + interest, payments);
    var monthly = (principal * x * interest) / (x - 1);

    // Check that the result is a finite number. If so, display the results.
    if (!isNaN(monthly) &&
      (monthly != Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY) &&
      (monthly != Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)) {

      document.loandata.payment.value = round(monthly);
      document.loandata.total.value = round(monthly * payments);
      document.loandata.totalinterest.value =
        round((monthly * payments) - principal);
    }
    // Otherwise, the user's input was probably invalid, so don't
    // display anything.
    else {

      document.loandata.payment.value = "";
      document.loandata.total.value = "";
      document.loandata.totalinterest.value = "";
    }
  }

// This simple method rounds a number to two decimal places.
function round(x) {
  return Math.round(x * 100) / 100;
} <
/script>
```

```html
<head>
  <title>JavaScript Loan Calculator</title>
</head>
<form name="loandata">
  <table border=0>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" th bgcolor="#0c77bb">
        <font color=white><b>Enter Loan Information:</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td bgcolor="#f1f1f1">Amount Borrowed:</td>
      <td bgcolor="#f1f1f1"><input type="text" name="principal" size="12" onchange="calculate();"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td bgcolor="#f1f1f1">Monthly Interest Rate (%):</td>
      <td bgcolor="#f1f1f1"><input type="text" name="interest" size="12" onchange="calculate();"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td bgcolor="#f1f1f1">Number of Monthly Payments:</td>
      <td bgcolor="#f1f1f1"><input type="text" name="years" size="12" onchange="calculate();"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#a0ce4e" colspan="2">
        <input type="button" value="Compute" onclick="calculate();"> </td>
      <td bgcolor="#cb4429"><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor=""></td>
      <td bgcolor="" </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td th bgcolor="#0c77bb" colspan="3">
        <b><font color=white>Payment Information:</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td bgcolor="#f1f1f1">Your monthly payment will be:</td>
      <td bgcolor="#f1f1f1"><input type="text" name="payment" size="12"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td bgcolor="#f1f1f1">Your total payment will be:</td>
      <td bgcolor="#f1f1f1"><input type="text" name="total" size="12"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td bgcolor="#f1f1f1">Your total interest payments will be:</td>
      <td bgcolor="#f1f1f1"><input type="text" name="totalinterest" size="12"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: How are you trying to add this to your site? You also don't need the `language` attribute on your `<script>` tag.

Comment: tried it, it aint working <script>some code</script>

Comment: Where did you try it? You aren't giving enough information to help.

Comment: Added the script part on a custom javascript field, then the html part on a page builder text block on the page

Answer (score 0):

It happened i had the code twice, removing one solved the problem